# Magento product image depending on attributes

Tags: magento, attributes, product

Is it possible to show the customer a product-image based on what **combination of attributes** he select? So that i set some rule in the backend for all kind of combinations and a picture for this combination? If i dont set a rule, the standard picture is displayed.

This is very usefull e.g. for the furniture-products where the customer can select maybe attributes like color, shape, wood-type and i can show him exacly a picture of a product with that attributes. In the backend i would set a rule like:

red / classic / cherry wood - red_classic_cherrywood.jpg

Comment: if you are working on magento 1.9 then it already come with `color swatch`. which will do work for you.

Comment: I allready bougth color swatch, but i think i have just fixed attributes (color, size etc.) what if i dont need color but other attributes?

Comment: What is a product type for this ? with configurable product it's possible. but not the way you are suggesting. is it simple/configurable ?

Comment: It is a configurable product but what would be the way?

Comment: with the configurable product, for each combination and creation of simple product you can add image and for that particular combination that picture appears.

Comment: @SumanK.C Ok so i create a configurable product made of simple products? Do you have something like a workflow?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a simmilar project. 
For combination of attributes you need **dependent custom options** with gallery feature.

See this extension: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dependent-custom-options-gallery.html

Comment: Ok and can i add multiple attributes? not 2, sometimes i need 10 or more.

Comment: Sure. I used something simmilar in a project with more then 20 custom options per product (with dependencies on each other).

Comment: And i can set a specific picture if a user sets all these 20 attributes to one unique combination?

Comment: Yes. Check the extension demo and specifications. The picture shown should be the one of the last selected custom option (which depends on the previous selected option)

Comment: Yes ok that helps but there is one problem. If the customer set attribute 1,2 and 3 and than just want to edit 1, everything starts from the beginning.

Comment: Exactly, and everything should be displayed acoording to the dependencies between the choosen custom options. Check the extension documentation and demo.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do if you customize code to meet your requirement & if you want to use customoptions, but if you customize this code I think you can achieve same on custom attributes also
http://inchoo.net/magento/create-a-color-switcher-in-magento/

You should give it a try